# ASP.NET C# reportviewer Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource, reportviewer

I am new to report viwer, I wanted to know that how to pass the select parameter to report viewer and also to data source? I need to pass the start date and end date to the data source for filtering data and also show in report viewer. Anyone suggest?

```
>     <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="Log_ReportViewer" runat="server" Height="545px" Width="962px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
> WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
>         <LocalReport ReportPath="Reporting\ReportRDLC File\LogReport.rdlc">
>             <DataSources>
>                 <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="SqlDataSource1" Name="Log" />
>             </DataSources> 
>         </LocalReport>
>     </rsweb:ReportViewer>
>     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:InvControlConnectionString %>"
> ProviderName="<%$
> ConnectionStrings:InvControlConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
> SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM logs WHERE log_createDate >= startDate AND log_createDate >= endDate">
>         <SelectParameters>
>             <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="endDate" QueryStringField="endDate" />
>             <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="startDate" QueryStringField="startDate" />
>         </SelectParameters>
>     </asp:SqlDataSource> </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the code behind, like that:

```
ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[yournumberofparamaters];
parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("name", value);
parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("name", value);
parameters[2] = new ReportParameter("name", value);
this.Log_ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: Hi i try this code before but it show me LocalProcessingException at the last line of code.

Comment: @FirionRedfield Share the exception message please.

Comment: An exception of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: This isn't the exception message.

Comment: I got only got this message

Comment: `LocalProcessingException` is the most generic error using `LocalReport`: you have to check its `InnerException.Message` to have more info about the problem.

Comment: @tezzo Hi, the exception i solve already. But another problem is report cant load the data. It stuck at report loading